# JavaScript sum array using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

My task is to sum elements of an array and add it to second parameter (number) using recursion.
Return only gives me last value of sum. I would appreciate any feedback :)

```
const getArraySum = (numbersArray, initialValue) => {
// let sum = initialValue

// for (let i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
//     sum += numbersArray[i]
// } return sum
if (numbersArray.length === 0 ) {
    return initialValue 
} else {
    let sum = 0
    sum += numbersArray[numbersArray.length-1]
    console.log (numbersArray)
    numbersArray.pop()
    console.log (sum)
    getArraySum (numbersArray)
    return sum + initialValue
} 
};

const result1 = getArraySum([4,7,10], 5)
console.log (result1)
```

Comment: why the `sum += numbersArray[numbersArray.length-1]` and the `pop()` method? isn't just simpler to iterate thru your array, sum every element and then sum the result with your second parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the return value of the recursive call to `getArraySum`. Instead, you should add it to the returned value:

```js
const getArraySum = (numbersArray, initialValue) => {
  if (numbersArray.length === 0) {
      return initialValue 
  } 
  return numbersArray.pop() + getArraySum(numbersArray, initialValue);
};

const result = getArraySum([4,7,10], 5)
console.log (result)
```

Note that the initialValue should only be taken into consideration once, in the end condition where the array is empty.

Comment: mutating the argument is hardly a good idea

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought that with every recursion last element will be added to my sum. That's why I've tried to return sum

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to split an array into `head` (=the first element or `null` for an empty array) and `tail` (everything else). Then, establish that the sum is `head + sum(tail)`:

```js
let sum = ([head = null, ...tail]) =>
    head === null ? 0 : head + sum(tail)

console.log(sum([1,2,3,4]))
```

Having an initial value is a silly requirement, but it goes the same way:

```js
let sum = ([head = null, ...tail], init = 0) =>
    init + (head === null ? 0 : head + sum(tail))


console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the single values a summing variable and return immediately if the array is empty.

Otherwise return the function call with a new shorter array and hte sum of `sum` and the first element.

```js
const
    getSum = (numbers, sum = 0) => {
        if (!numbers.length) return sum;
        return getSum(numbers.slice(1), sum + numbers[0]);
    };

console.log (getSum([4, 7, 10], 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the array has an element, return last element (`pop`) plus `getArraySum([rest of the array])`, otherwise return `initial value`:

```js
const getArraySum = (numbersArray, initialValue) => {
    if (numbersArray.length === 0 ) {
        return initialValue 
    } else {
        return numbersArray.pop() + getArraySum(numbersArray, initialValue);
    } 
};

const result1 = getArraySum([4,7,10], 5)
console.log (result1)
```